# iPhone 7 - xcode shows correctly but when i execute on device the element is invisible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have this `Main.storyboard`, but when i move the `<rect>` from `x="20" y="28" width="96" height="128"` into `<rect key="frame" x="416" y="496" width="96" height="96"/>`

Then on real iPhone 7 i do not see that element at all.

Why is it getting lost? how can you tell the `<rect>` to be aligned always on bottom right as fixed?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="9060" systemVersion="15B42" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" initialViewController="vXZ-lx-hvc">
<dependencies>
<deployment identifier="iOS"/>
<plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="9051"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
<!--View Controller-->
<scene sceneID="ufC-wZ-h7g">
<objects>
<viewController id="vXZ-lx-hvc" customClass="ViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
<layoutGuides>
<viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="jyV-Pf-zRb"/>
<viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="2fi-mo-0CV"/>
</layoutGuides>
<view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="kh9-bI-dsS">
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
<subviews>
<view contentMode="scaleAspectFit" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fIq-yw-hCc" userLabel="Remote View" customClass="RTCEAGLVideoView">
<rect key="frame" x="-140" y="-16" width="600" height="600"/>
<animations/>
<color key="backgroundColor" red="0.40000000000000002" green="0.40000000000000002" blue="0.40000000000000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
</view>
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="oEs-Uu-HsQ" userLabel="Local View">
<rect key="frame" x="416" y="496" width="96" height="96" />
<animations/>
<color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
</view>
</subviews>
<animations/>
<color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
</view>
<connections>
<outlet property="localView" destination="oEs-Uu-HsQ" id="V9h-Lg-Z2G"/>
<outlet property="remoteView" destination="fIq-yw-hCc" id="tJt-sU-42X"/>
</connections>
</viewController>
<placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="x5A-6p-PRh" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
</objects>
</scene>
</scenes>
</document>
```

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController () <SocketIOSignalingDelegate, VideoViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet VideoView *remoteView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *localView;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use auto-layout, there are many guides out there. e.g. this one from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html). It looks like you are using the old style auto-resizing masks, but then have disabled converting these into constraints. I'd recommend learning how to create auto-layout constraints in interface builder.